# Why the java method Enum.valueof invoke the enum type constructor?

Tags: java, enums

I have built this kind of data enum:

```
enum Sexo {
    HOMBRE("H"), MUJER("M"), OTRO("O"); 
    private String sexo;        
    private Sexo(String sexo){ 
        System.out.println("constructor del tipo enum");
        this.sexo=sexo;
    }
 }
```

Then, in the Main method i just do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sexo sexo1 = Enum.valueOf(Sexo.class, "HOMBRE"); 
    Sexo sexo2 = Enum.valueOf(Sexo.class, "MUJER"); 
    Sexo.valueOf("OTRO");

}
```

then, i have this on the console:

```
constructor del tipo enum
constructor del tipo enum
constructor del tipo enum
```

i understand that i have a call to the constructor for each enum type whit the sentence "Sexo" (name of the enum type). But: 
why the constructor is running just once? note that i have two instances and one direct call to the class.

Comment: The statement `HOMBRE("H"), MUJER("M"), OTRO("O")` calls the constructors. Not your `valueOf` method.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isnt the method `valueOf` that calls the constructor.

The constructor of an `enum` is called for every literal when the class is first used. So in your case thats before the first call to `Enum.valueOf`.

The three calls to the constructor are caused by the three literals not your three calls to `valueOf`.

Comment: @HectorEstigarribia If an answer helped you solve the issue, consider **accepting** it, thanks.

Comment: sorry.. i accepted the answer with the accept option, thanks